# Images wont load in jinja/python

Tags: python, image, api, url, jinja2

Heyo guys! I am facing a problem with my html page. It is supposed to load gifs from GIHPY(i installed their API and its working perfectly). But when i try to display the results from search(we made our own search engine which loads results from giphy) i doenst show anything, while it is supposed to show pictures. My application code is as follows:

```
def gifs():

if request.method == "POST":
    # create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()
    api_key = 'hidden'
    q = request.form.get("gif")
    limit = 5
    offset = 0
    rating = 'g'
    lang = 'en'
    fmt = 'json'
    i = 0
    gifimages = []

    api_response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(api_key, q, limit=limit, offset=offset, rating=rating, lang=lang, fmt=fmt)
    while i < len(api_response.data):
        gifimages.append(api_response.data[i].images.original.url)
        i = i + 1

    return render_template("loadedgifs.html", gifimages = gifimages)

return render_template("gifs.html")
```

My template looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    LoadedGifs
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<table style="width: 100%; padding: 15px;">
<tr style = "background-color: ##CEF6E3; color: #537fbe;">
<th>Gifs</th>

{% for gif in gifimages %}

    <td><img src = "{{gif.url}}" alt = "plaatje"></td>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

When i print the variable gifimages it shows a list with valid urls. But for some reason when i inspect the page, it sais

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the contents of `gifimages`?

Comment: ['https://media1.giphy.com/media/JIX9t2j0ZTN9S/giphy.gif', 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/vFKqnCdLPNOKc/giphy.gif'] This is the basic structure of gifimages. For some reason it leaves the https:// out of the comment...

Comment: So, in this case, `gifimages` is a list of STRINGS, not objects. So I think your template should use `src={{  gif  }}` as opposed to `src={{ gif.url }}`